# Netbeans project: how to add dependency without having a pom-file?

Tags: maven, netbeans, dependencies

I'm trying to make an old Netbeans project run.

However, certain references are broken:

[image]

Normally, one would install mongoldb-java-driver by augmenting the pom-file accordingly, see:  https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/

However, this Netbeans project does not have a pom file (I don't know why).

How can I add the missing files and folders to the project without a pom-file?

Answer (score 0):

You can try downloading the Netbeans 8.2 from Oracle directly as it will contain by default the maven plugin and in this case might solve your problem.